# Superglues for higher heat applications?

Tags: adhesive

I am currently building a specialized computer. One of the parts I ordered includes a clip to hold it to another part (there's no real tension, it's just a clip).  Since there is almost no tension on the clip, a little super glue I think should be fine to repair it.

I am trying to find out if there are any super-glues (non-epoxy) which can be used for higher heat applications? According to the loctite website, it's good to about 82 degrees celsius. The same for gorilla glue.

In a perfect world, my operating temperature will never exceed 65 degrees celsius, but that's a sunny day scenario. If some fans die, it could easily skyrocket from 80-90 degrees celsius before the system locks up from overheating. I need to make sure that the clip doesn't come apart as a result of that heat since it could damage other components if it came loose.

Comment: What are the parts? What are they made of?  If the clip is holding on a heat sink they make adhesives for that specific purpose.

Comment: It looks like pvc plastic from a PCI-Express socket. The socket itself is in tact, but the clip that holds the GPU in place is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You are either going to use glue which has melting points - I can't believe that there are no glues that can't handle computer heat - or caulk/silicone which may handle heat better but has some elasticity to it so it may move or have issues too.

Really best options are epoxy or weld it.  If you don't want either of those than you have to choose the one of the two above that you can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Silicone adhesives generally will withstand high temperatures, often into the hundreds of degrees, but be sure to check the product specifications.

Glues classified as "super glue" tend to have fast adhesion and drying times but generally are not all that strong.